# Map properties of any generic object (including nested objects) to array of linked lists

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to infer a table column structure from any generic object. This object can have properties of any type. Every property that is not of type object should represent a column. If the property is another object, this object's properties should also represent a column (and so on).

Say my object looks like the following.

```ts
export interface Event {
  name: string;
  meta: {
    created: Date,
    updated: Date,
  },
  some_data: {
    nested_data: {
      some_nested_data: string;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to then display a list of these objects in a table like so.

| name | created | updated | some_nested_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1/1/2020 | 2/1/2020 | some value |
| Anna | 1/2/2020 | 2/2/2020 | some value |

Important: I'm trying to make it work for any generic object.

## What I have tried

To try and achieve this, I've created a Column class.

```ts
export class Column extends LinkedList<ObjectProperty>
```

Which is supported by the following code.

```ts
export type ObjectProperty = { name: string, type: string }

export interface ILinkedList<T> {
  insertInBegin(data: T): Node<T>;
  insertAtEnd(data: T): Node<T>;
  deleteNode(node: Node<T>): void;
  traverse(): T[];
  size(): number;
  search(comparator: (data: T) => boolean): Node<T> | null;
}

export class Node<T> {
  public next: Node<T> | null = null;
  public prev: Node<T> | null = null;
  constructor(public data: T) {}
}
```

I'm using `LinkedList<ObjectProperty>`, so I can always access any object property value in a column by giving an array of property names (I use the `traverse()` function to get the array) and parsing the object until I get the value.

I think I'm then able to display data with something like this.

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
      <th *ngFor="let property of column.traverse(); let i = index">
        {{ column.getLast().data.name }}
      </th>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let object of dataSorted; let i = index">
    <td *ngFor="let column of columns">
      {{ getColumnValue(column, object) }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

## The problem

I get lost trying to map an object's keys to an array of Columns with a linked list filled with object properties.

I've tried to create functions with variations of `Object.keys(object).map()` and a bunch of recursive functions, but I can't seem to figure it out. Especially because it needs to support nested objects.

**In short: I need to map a generic object's properties to an array of Column objects (see Column class).**

Any help in assisting me forward is very much appreciated!

NB: If I need to add more information or resources, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it very complex while you only need an "simple" array.
If I understand correctly, you have a generic component to display an array of items.
In this case, you can use the keyvalue pipe from angular : https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

component.ts :

```
export class MyComponent {
   items = [
        { id: 0, name: "foo" },
        { id: 1, name: "bar" },
    ];
    items2 = [
        { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
        { firstName: "James", lastName: "Bond" },
    ];

    keys = Object.keys(this.items[0]);
    keys2 = Object.keys(this.items2[0]);
```

}

And you component.html :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let key of keys">{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td *ngFor="let keyValue of item | keyvalue">{{keyValue.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let key of keys2">{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items2">
            <td *ngFor="let keyValue of item | keyvalue">{{keyValue.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can also transform your data yourself on your ngOnInit : `itemValues = items.map(item => Object.values(item))`

Comment: I've tried your solution. This will work for direct property keys and values, but it will not work for my column names nor my row values if a value is of type object; see [this image](https://imgur.com/ZhavQhJ).

Comment: As you can have object of object of object ... there is not end, and no way for your generic table to know how to display each one.
So you can specify that the user (of your component) has to provide a "stringified" table, or a method to stringify it yourself. You can also let him display each column using ng-content / ng-template